# Laravel: Query to return data depending the ID I pass in URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

First of all excuse me if when you read all the question you think isn't clear or question should be edited, please, make a edit and i will accept it.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('project/{id}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@showProject', 'as' => 'admin.projects.show']);
```

**What I want to do**

Render a view with information of two tables.

**Tables information**

First table is called projects and I have this fields: id, slug, order, public, pathheader and pathhome.

Second table is called project_translation where I have this fields: id, locale, project_id, title, description.

**Query problem**

I need a query where I get the info of the project I pass on url. This will look like this (is working):

```
$project = Project::find($id);
```

And I print the data with {{$project->fieldname}}

Now, I want to retrieve the data of the translation with the same project id. I was doing it with:

```
$translation = ProjectTranslation::find($id);
```

But of course, return me the data of the ProjectTranslation with the ID i passed on URL.

**Question**

How should look the query where I get the data of the project_translations with the same project_id ?

Thanks a lot, if need more information or just isn't clear. Please put a comment.

Comment: Do you want it with joins or different query ?

Comment: I prefer know the two ways. Always is good learn new ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `$id` to find all records on `ProjectTranslation` with `project_id` equals to `$id` like this:

```
$translation = ProjectTranslation::where('project_id',$id)->get();
```

If you just have one record on `ProjectTranslation`, then you can get like:

```
$translation = ProjectTranslation::where('project_id',$id)->first();
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: It's successfully. Thanks Mate. Maybe i will have more questions about query in this days. If you are interested, be attentive to my profile.

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer Congrats you have got solution,  if any problem feel free to ask :D :D

Comment: Hi @SagarGautam are you here? Maybe you can help me

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer any problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

```
$project = Project::find($id);
$translation = ProjectTranslation::where('project_id', $id)->first();
```

Do that in the controller and then you can pass this data to the view:

```
return view('sample', ['project' => $project, 'translation' => $translation]);
```

Comment: Perfect @Marcin thanks a lot for your fast answer.  When you do: `where('project_id',$id)` you are comparing the project_id field with the id you pass on URL true?  It's possible to do something like: `$translation = ProjectTranslation::where($id, $project->id);` ? Compare the $id with the id value of project table? Thanks mate!

Comment: This function gives you all database entries where field `project_id == $id`, then you can use ->get() to get an array of entries or ->first() if you want to get the first matched value.

Comment: Actually I have two translations for each project. So should look like: `$translation = ProjectTranslation::where('project_id',$id)->get();` ? So i will need make a foreach.

Comment: Yes! use ->get() and then a foreach to iterate through this returned array.

Comment: Done ;) Maybe i will have more questions about query in this days. If you are interested, be attentive to my profile.

Comment: Hi @Marcin are you here? Maybe you can help me